# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS-After "error"in Classic Menu Indicator,problems launchpad icons resizing

Tags: icons

Please,can someone tell me why after I had an"internal error"in Classic Menu Indicator,I removed it.Later I tried to reduce launchpad icons ,I had many problems.Lost many icons in System Settings Panel,many icons changed etc.Now I don't really know what can be done to come back.Can someone help me.Thank you

Comment: Are you saying you scaled the launcher icons larger and some have disappeared below? If so move your mouse downwards or use scroll wheel to make them visible.

Comment: No,I reduced the size of icons from System Settings/Apperance and many disappeared.In the System Setting Panel and many changed everywhere,in the Launchpad,at the top right(battery,audio...)Thank you

Comment: I guess you tried to restore the size back to the original setting without any luck?

Comment: Exactly,it didn't change nothing

Comment: I'm sorry to say I've resized icons before and never had your problem. It sounds like a bug to me.